# Ubuntu server 18.04 - No IP address with Netplan

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, netplan

**Background:**

*Hardware:
Thinkpad X301*

In the installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server (64-bit) the installation was stuck at the network setup portion of the installation. The network setup timed out and no IP address seemed to be assigned to the ethernet interface (enp0s25 in this case).

I instead downloaded the alternate installer and the installation went smoothly and dhcp was autoconfigured (which also works flawlessly in the 16.04 server installation). However after the installation 18.04 hangs at the "Waiting for network to be configured" message. After 2 minutes it continues and lets me access the terminal.

**Configuration**

*Output of ifconfig after boot*

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::222:68ff:fe0c:bf44  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:22:68:0c:bf:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 225  bytes 59069 (59.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 3686 (3.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf0600000-f0620000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 528  bytes 32112 (32.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 528  bytes 32112 (32.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

*Output of ip addr show after boot*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:68:0c:bf:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::222:68ff:fe0c:bf44/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6a:1d:ee:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

*01-netcfg.yaml*

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
```

**Temporary solution**

Tried using `sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.107 dev enp0s25`
- IP is assigned to the interface but no internet

Then i tried `sudo dhclient -v enp0s25`
- Which assigns an IP and internet works

Output after sudo dhclient -v enp0s25

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:68:0c:bf:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.107/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::222:68ff:fe0c:bf44/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6a:1d:ee:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**In summary - The question**

What needs to be changed in order for ubuntu to obtain a dynamic IP address on boot by itself?

Comment: Do you control your DHCP server?  Ubuntu Server 18.04 does not use dhclient as the DHCP client, but uses systemd-networkd's built-in DHCP client instead.  It seems the DHCP server is not handing out an address to this client.  You may want to do a packet capture of the traffic to see what's happening (`sudo tcpdump -i enp0s25 -s 1500 -w dhcp-packet-capture.pcap port 67 or port 68` followed by 'sudo netplan apply') and submit this as a bug report against the systemd package in Ubuntu.